# After upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 - Tap to click is not reliable anymore

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, synaptics, libinput, tap-to-click

I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 and realized tap to click is not reliable anymore. Approximately 40% of taps simply does nothing. Did you notice similar issues? Is it possible to fix this? (I use lenovo l450).

Edit: I use xorg session.

Comment: is laptop-mode-tools installed?

Comment: laptop-mode-tools is not installed

Answer (score 11):

What ended up working for me was to remove the synaptics driver:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

followed by a reboot. After that the touchpad worked again. I have a Dell XPS 15 9650.

Comment: oh thanks! It also fixed touchpad disabling functionality!

Answer (score 6):

Installing [Touchpad Indicator](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) worked for me!

Comment: Works for me, perhaps this tool should be included in Ubuntu...?

Comment: It works like a charm. Tested on LG Gram 2-in-1 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 unity desktop

Answer (score 2):

**Adjusting Mouse Settings**

Sounds like you just need to do some custom configuring to your touchpad to increase the sensitivity FingerLow (minimum amount of pressure required to register a tap). This can be accomplished with synclient:

First check your settings:

```
$ synclient -l
```

Then you can adjust your FingerLow/FingerHigh (or other) settings:

```
$ synclient FingerLow=2
```

Once you figure out your correct settings you will need to put them in a startup script as the synclient options will be reset on reboot. You can see more options, get more info and learn how to make a configuration script with this [Great Tutorial on Touchpad Options](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/tweak-your-touchpad-to-taste-in-linux/).

You can also use xinput to get info and tweak some settings per this [Great Tutorial on Configuring HID Devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down?noredirect=1&lq=1). Here is a quick summary:

First, find your device name and ID:

```
$ xinput --list
```

Look at the output to determine your device name or id number and list its available properties:

```
$ xinput --list-props ID
```

This will show you the available options you can set. Then you can set them like this:

```
$ xinput --set-prop ID 'prop name' VAL
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Tapping doesn't work at all since upgrading to ubuntu and fiddling with `synclient` doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: is not this because they switched from synaptics to libinput? will synclient work with libinput?

Comment: synclient is *not* installed by default in 18.04, so this doesn't seem to be the preferred way of doing things any more...?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration recommendations above are great, I have exactly the same problem and it is definitely a sensitivity problem. I have found that an almost imperceptible tap, literally almost barely even touching the pad, raises the success rate of a click to around 90%. After years of plopping my finger on the pad it is a bit of an adjustment so I will be fiddling with the settings.

...

oh man that was easy...it was definitely the default spread between FingerLow and FingerHigh which left too small a tap range the following seemed to be the sweet spot...

FingerLow=25
FingerHigh=80

which in my case ended up only being one command:

synclient FingerHigh=80